# Convert part of string to URL when displayed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I browsed around for a solution and I am sure it's a simple question but still not sure how to do that. So, I have a string that contains many words and some times it has links in it. For example:

> I like the website http://somesitehere.com/somepage.html and I suggest you try it too.

I want to display the string in my view and have all links automatically converted to URLs.

```
@Model.MyText
```

Even StackOverflow gets it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Hunter is right.
In addition i found complete implementation in C#: http://weblogs.asp.net/farazshahkhan/archive/2008/08/09/regex-to-find-url-within-text-and-make-them-as-link.aspx.

**In case original link goes down**

***VB.Net implementation***

```
Protected Function MakeLink(ByVal txt As String) As String
    Dim regx As New Regex("http://([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&amp;\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

    Dim mactches As MatchCollection = regx.Matches(txt)

    For Each match As Match In mactches
        txt = txt.Replace(match.Value, "<a href='" & match.Value & "'>" & match.Value & "</a>")
    Next

    Return txt
End Function
```

***C#.Net implementation***

```
protected string MakeLink(string txt) 
{ 
   Regex regx = new Regex("http://([\\w+?\\.\\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*)?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 

   MatchCollection mactches = regx.Matches(txt); 

   foreach (Match match in mactches) { 
    txt = txt.Replace(match.Value, "<a href='" + match.Value + "'>" + match.Value + "</a>"); 
   }
   return txt; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that would be to do a Regular Expression match on a chunk of text and replace that url string with an anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

Another regex that can be used with KvanTTT answer, and has the added benefit of accepting https urls

> https?://([\w+?.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~!\@#\$\%\^\&*()_-\=+\/\?.:\;\'\,]*)?

.net string representation:

```
"https?://([\\w+?\\.\\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*)?"
```